# «Специалисты по специальностям» — избыточно или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Грамотно ли использовать фразу «специалисты по специальностям», например, такой контекст: «вузы, готовящие специалистов по специальностям 010101 — юриспруденция и 020202 — информатика»?

Answer (score 2):

Смысловой избыточности, то есть **плеоназма**, тут нет, но есть **тавтология** — повторение очевидно однокоренных слов в рамках предложения. Это ошибка речевого/стилистического характера.

Я думаю, лучшим вариантом будет такой:

> > специалистов по **направлениям**

P.S. Определения тавтологии и плеоназма бывают разные, так что я использую их с известной долей условности.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, плохо звучит. Можно сказать, например: "вузы, готовящие по следующим специальностям..." или "вузы, где можно получить следующие специальности..."

Answer (score 0):

"специалисты по специальностям" - это тавтология ( как: масло масляное).
Нежелательно употреблять в речи такие выражения, так как нарушаются речевые нормы.